# Improve Custom Post Permalink Structure

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I've created a custom post type, with an easy permalink structure. Now I want to enhance this permalink structure with some extra information.

```
public function custom_post_mission() {
        $labels = array(
           ...
        );

        $args = array(
            'labels'        => $labels,
            'description'   => __( 'Holds our missions and specific data', TEXT_DOMAIN ),
            'public'        => true,
            'menu_position' => 5,
            'supports'      => array( 'title', 'author', 'editor' ),
            'has_archive'   => true,
            'menu_icon'     => plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'img/mission.png',
            'register_meta_box_cb' => array( $this, 'add_custom_box' )
        );
        register_post_type( 'mission', $args ); 
    }
```

With the above coding I got the following permalink structure: `http://localhost/wordpress/mission/<post-title>/`

This structure I would like to improve to the following one:
`http://localhost/wordpress/mission/<year>/<month>/<post-title>/`

How can I do this? It would be nice if there is a way to transfer the old permalink structure to the new one, but it's not necessary.

BR & Thanks,

mybecks

/E: enhanced my code with code example provided by ravi

```
public function custom_post_mission() {
            global $wp_rewrite;
            $labels = array(
               ...
            );

            $args = array(
                'labels'        => $labels,
                'description'   => __( 'Holds our missions and specific data', TEXT_DOMAIN ),
                'public'        => true,
                'menu_position' => 5,
                'supports'      => array( 'title', 'author', 'editor' ),
                'has_archive'   => true,
                'menu_icon'     => plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'img/mission.png',
                'register_meta_box_cb' => array( $this, 'add_custom_box' )
            );
            register_post_type( 'mission', $args );

            $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('mission', 'mission/%year%/%monthnum%/%mission%/', true, 1);
            add_rewrite_rule('mission/([0-9]{4})/(.+)/?$', 'index.php?mission=$matches[2]', 'top');
            $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(); // !!! 
        }
```

This creates the following permalink structure:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/mission/%year%/%monthnum%/<mission-title>/
```

But the `%year%` and `%monthnum%` placeholder couldn't be replaced with the corresponding values.

/E2:
I finally get it to work.
I needed a filter which resolves the placeholders:

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'mission_permalink', 10, 3);

function mission_permalink( $permalink, $post_id, $leavename ) {
    $post = get_post($post_id);
        $rewritecode = array(
            '%year%',
            '%monthnum%',
            '%day%',
            '%hour%',
            '%minute%',
            '%second%',
            $leavename? '' : '%postname%',
            '%post_id%',
            '%category%',
            '%author%',
            $leavename? '' : '%pagename%',
        );

        if ( '' != $permalink && !in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft')) ) {
            $unixtime = strtotime($post->post_date);

            $category = '';
            if ( strpos($permalink, '%category%') !== false ) {
                $cats = get_the_category($post->ID);
                if ( $cats ) {
                    usort($cats, '_usort_terms_by_ID'); // order by ID
                    $category = $cats[0]->slug;
                    if ( $parent = $cats[0]->parent )
                        $category = get_category_parents($parent, false, '/', true) . $category;
                }
                // show default category in permalinks, without
                // having to assign it explicitly
                if ( empty($category) ) {
                    $default_category = get_category( get_option( 'default_category' ) );
                    $category = is_wp_error( $default_category ) ? '' : $default_category->slug;
                }
            }

            $author = '';
            if ( strpos($permalink, '%author%') !== false ) {
                $authordata = get_userdata($post->post_author);
                $author = $authordata->user_nicename;
            }

            $date = explode(" ",date('Y m d H i s', $unixtime));
            $rewritereplace =
            array(
                $date[0],
                $date[1],
                $date[2],
                $date[3],
                $date[4],
                $date[5],
                $post->post_name,
                $post->ID,
                $category,
                $author,
                $post->post_name,
            );
            $permalink = str_replace($rewritecode, $rewritereplace, $permalink);

            // wp_die($permalink );
        } else { // if they're not using the fancy permalink option
        }
        return $permalink;
    }
```

and I there was a small error in the add_rewrite_rule regexp.
The correct one: `add_rewrite_rule('mission/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.+)/?$', 'index.php?mission=$matches[3]', 'top');`

Comment: You don't have to add permastruct and rewrite rule, just use the `rewrite` argument when you register your post type and WordPress does this for you. Also **do not** flush rules on every request as your code does now.

Answer (score 1):

you can use and manage your permalink for custom post type. [Custom Post Type Permalinks](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/screenshots/)

[image]

```
add_action('init', 'my_rewrite');
function my_rewrite() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('typename', 'typename/%year%/%postname%/', true, 1);
    add_rewrite_rule('typename/([0-9]{4})/(.+)/?$', 'index.php?typename=$matches[2]', 'top');
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(); // !!!
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this plugin suggestion, it works fine. But I'm searching a programmatically way, too. BR

Comment: thanks again for your helpful code example. I have adopt it so far, but it seems like the %year%/%monthnum% placeholder couldn't replaced with the corresponding values.

Comment: Flushing rewrites on every request is very bad.